# The specified type member 'res_updateWithItemTest' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var COAUpdate = from tbl in entity.res_COA_template
            where tbl.res_coa_template_item_code == Item_test_ItemCode
            select new COATemplate
            {
            res_coa_template_id = tbl.res_coa_template_id,
            res_updateWithItemTestProp =tbl.res_updateWithItemTest.Value   // Getting error here
            }).ToList();
```

[image: Here is the column in the database as you can see in the image]

I have added the `res_updateWithItemTest (bit, null)` column to the existing table in SQL.

And I also added the property with same name in the context class file also.

But when I am trying to get the particular field (`res_updateWithItemTest`) value from the database, I get an error

> The specified type member 'res_updateWithItemTest' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

But all other fields are fetched correctly.

Please help me.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How EXACTLY did you add that property and column? Was it part of the original schema or was it added later? If later, please explain EXACTLY what you did to add it.

Comment: Actually I have added column manually in SQL, Property manually in Model, and later did "Update model from database" option in EDMX file

Comment: The image you've shown looks like Server Explorer. What about the EF designer?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I reverted EDMX update and re-done again. And its working fine now. Thank you..

Comment: But one more problem is that the value is coming null. Could you please help?

Comment: That is a different question and requires specific additional information. Simply put though, if you're getting `null` in your app then it's because the database doesn't contain a value. I have to wonder why you've made the column nullable and then written code that assumes that there will always be a value.